# Multiple Operation Queues with Different priorities

Tags: ios, uiimage, avfoundation

Good day, here's what i am trying to do:

- i have a photo processing app that takes images using AVFoundation
- i have a DeviceMotion queue that is processing device position at 60Hz
- when image is taken, it needs to be cropped and saved. DeviceMotion needs to keep running and interface updated without delays

what i am seeing is: updates to interface from DeviceMotion queue are being frozen for the duration of image crop.

this is how i start updates for DeviceMotion:

```
self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0f/60.0f;
gyroQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:gyroQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error){
        [NSThread setThreadPriority:1.0];
        [self processMotion:motion withError:error];
    }];
```

when images is returned from AVFoundation it is added to the queue for processing:

```
imageProcessingQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [imageProcessingQueue setName:@"ImageProcessingQueue"];
    [imageProcessingQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

//[imageProcessingQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    //[self processImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
//}];

    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(processImage:) object:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    [operation setThreadPriority:0.0];
    [operation setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryLow];
    [imageProcessingQueue addOperation:operation];
```

and the method for processing the image:

```
- (void)processImage:(UIImage*)image {

    CGSize cropImageSize = CGSizeMake(640,960);

    UIImage *croppedImage  = [image resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:cropImageSize interpolationQuality:kImageCropInterpolationQuality];

    NSData *compressedImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage, kJpegCompression);

    [self.doc addPhoto:compressedImageData];
}
```

the issue is:

- devicemotion updates are blocked for the duration of image crop when image is processed using the NSOperationQueue

if i process the image using performSelectorInBackground - it works as desired (no delays to DeviceMotion queue)

> ```
> [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(processImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
> ```

any ideas on where my understanding of background threading needs an update? :)

PS. I have asked this question earlier but it got nowhere, so this is a re-post

Comment: where are you setting `queuePriority` on your operation queue?

Comment: i am setting queuePriority on the NSInvocationOperation, see updated code above...

Comment: why are you setting the priority to `0.0` and not one of `NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryHigh` or `NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryHigh`? `0` (not a float) is the standard priority.

Comment: just tried setting queuePriority to NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryLow, without any changes. I am suspecting it has more to do with the threadPriority, as the DeviceMotion updates are coming to another queue. For threadPriorty 0.0 is the lowest possible, which is what i need for image processing.

Comment: Your call to `[NSThread setThreadPriority:1.0]` should, at the very least, be paired with a similar call that resets the thread to its original priority. You do not own the thread, NSOperationQueue/GCD does. My best guess here is that device motion updates get sent to the main queue and, from there, forwarded to the queue you specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a solution (or solid workaround) for this issue:

instead of routing deviceMotion updates to the queue using `startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue`, i have created a CADisplayLink timer and it is not interfering with other background queues - while it is matching screen refresh rate it's given highest priority by it's nature:

```
[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];

gyroTimer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(processMotion)];
    [gyroTimer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```